# What is $1^1+3^3+5^5+7^7+…+n^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was asked this by a friend. Hoping someone to answer. The goal here is to find a general formula for the expression.

Comment: The series grows sharply.  It makes more sense to look for an asymptotic approximation rather than a general formula.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554836/sum-of-self-power?noredirect=1), which has also no explicit formula. Your friend can have a look at this post.

Comment: I derived a complete asymptotic expansion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4191069).

Answer (score 4):

For these problems, you can always search the OEIS with the first few terms.

https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C28%2C3153&sort=&language=english&go=Search

You see that this sequence has been considered by others before, that there's no known exact formula (at least not there, but I have a feeling there's likely no closed formula at all), but there is an asymptotic estimate.